Is this weeping willow dying?
I have a Kilmarnock miniature weeping willow. planted 2 years ago. This year it has new leaves on top, but underneath the branches seem dead. Also, the new branches are not hanging down but growing straight out: will they droop with time, or would putting weights on them help?
I live in northern France, I have clay soil. We have a mild climate, and it was extremely wet for a prolonged time this spring. Last year was a record for dryness, but I watered it.


Are the new branches that don't weep sprouting beneath the graft?

@YosefBaskin the photo is a bit blurry, but I think they are originating from the weeping branches. Let’s wait for the OP.

There are so many rules to this site! And yes, I have read them, and taken the tour. Please send the link to the site you want me to post on as here it's called G and L

What I mean is, the App opens on the G and L site, so tell me how to get the page you want me to be on as the desktop icon. We are not all as computer skilled

@RedFox21 LOTS of rules, but you're already getting the hang of it :-)
